# How to extract JWT token payload when token is expired in Python JWT

Tags: python, flask, jwt, backend

I am unable to extract JWT token payload after the JWT token expires in Python JWT package.
I am using flask API for backend development and the implementation is in the middleware.

Below is my code:

```py
import jwt
from flask import request
from functools import wraps
from werkzeug.exceptions import Forbidden, Unauthorized

def admin_rights_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def _decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        config = readConfig()
        secretKey = config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"]
        algorithm = config["JWT_ENCODING_ALGORITHM"]
        token = None
        if "Authorization" in request.headers:
            data = request.headers["Authorization"]
            token = str.replace(str(data), "Bearer ", "")
        try:
            if not token or (not _ruleUserObj.getRuleUserFromToken(token)):
                data = jwt.decode(token, secretKey, algorithms=algorithm)
                raise Unauthorized("Token is missing")
            data = jwt.decode(token, secretKey, algorithms=algorithm)
            if getTokenDurationDifference(token) == -1:
                raise jwt.InvalidTokenError
            currentUser = _ruleUserObj.getRuleUser(data["sub"]["username"])
            if not len(currentUser) > 0:
                raise jwt.InvalidTokenError
            if currentUser["isAdmin"] == False:
                raise Forbidden()
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            _ruleUserObj.updatedRuleUserSessionRemToken(data["sub"]["username"])
            raise Unauthorized("Signature expired. Please log in again.")
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            _ruleUserObj.updatedRuleUserSessionRemToken(data["sub"]["username"])
            raise Unauthorized("Invalid token. Please log in again.")

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return _decorated
```

Comment: Split by the dots, base64 decode the middle part, JSON decode.

Comment: Can you show an example of the same @KlausD.

Comment: Can you try to implement it?

Comment: Have updated the answer and tried it out and it is working as expected. Thanks for the simple hack once again @KlausD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out the solution in the jwt package in python. Below is the link for reference:
https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-the-claimset-without-validation
Below is the code change which I did for the above:

```
jwt.decode(
                        token,
                        secretKey,
                        algorithms=algorithm,
                        options={"verify_signature": False},
                    )
                )["sub"]["username"]
            )
```

After merging the code with the main code it looks like below:

```
import jwt
from flask import request
from functools import wraps
from werkzeug.exceptions import Forbidden, Unauthorized

def admin_rights_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def _decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        config = readConfig()
        secretKey = config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"]
        algorithm = config["JWT_ENCODING_ALGORITHM"]
        token = None
        if "Authorization" in request.headers:
            data = request.headers["Authorization"]
            token = str.replace(str(data), "Bearer ", "")
        try:
            if not token or (not _ruleUserObj.getRuleUserFromToken(token)):
                data = jwt.decode(token, secretKey, algorithms=algorithm)
                raise Unauthorized("Token is missing")
            data = jwt.decode(token, secretKey, algorithms=algorithm)
            if getTokenDurationDifference(token) == -1:
                raise jwt.InvalidTokenError
            currentUser = _ruleUserObj.getRuleUser(data["sub"]["username"])
            if not len(currentUser) > 0:
                raise jwt.InvalidTokenError
            if currentUser["isAdmin"] == False:
                raise Forbidden()
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            _ruleUserObj.updatedRuleUserSessionRemToken(
                (
                    jwt.decode(
                        token,
                        secretKey,
                        algorithms=algorithm,
                        options={"verify_signature": False},
                    )
                )["sub"]["username"]
            )
            raise Unauthorized("Signature expired. Please log in again.")
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            _ruleUserObj.updatedRuleUserSessionRemToken(
                (
                    jwt.decode(
                        token,
                        secretKey,
                        algorithms=algorithm,
                        options={"verify_signature": False},
                    )
                )["sub"]["username"]
            )
            raise Unauthorized("Invalid token. Please log in again.")

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return _decorated
```

There is alternative way to decode the jwt token if it is expired:
As suggested by @KlausD. Below is the implementation:

```
import base64
import json
tokenSplit = token.split(".")
json.loads((base64.b64decode(tokenSplit[1])).decode("utf-8"))
```

Thanks to @KlausD. for the simple hack

Comment: It didn't work here, using the pyjwt==1.7.1 library with the options parameter like this: options = { "verify_signature": False }

It only worked when informing the parameter "verify=False", like this:

payload = jwt.decode(jwt=token, key=secret, verify=False, algorithms = [ 'HS256' ])

Comment: I have given alternative solution as well, which is crude way of decoding jwt token. Let me know even if that solution didn't help you

Comment: If you want to check the the payload *without* having to worry about the **expiry date**, you can use `options={"verify_exp": False}`. Good for renewing JWT tokens when an access token might have already expired but you need to see the payload so you can verify the `user_id`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `jwt.decode(token,...,options={"verify_signature":False})`,
but according to the documentation, the integrity or authenticity of the claimset cannot be trusted in that case.

Another solution is to use a `leeway` parameter with a big value, that way you can check the integrity of the token in case it has expired within that period: `jwt.decode(token,...,leeway=datetime.timedelta(days=3))`

for more details: https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#expiration-time-claim-exp

Answer (score 0):

If the options parameter doesn't work like this: options = { "verify_signature": False }

Using the lib pyjwt==1.7.1 try to inform the parameter "verify=False", like this here:

payload = jwt.decode(jwt=token, key=secret, verify=False, algorithms = [ 'HS256' ])